# html embed swf sound

Tags: html, flash

I've had this sound effect play on my site for months now when a user gets a mail. Suddenly it's stopped working in Chrome, but works in other browsers. The code is:

```
<object width=0 height=0>
    <param name=sound value=beep.swf>
    <embed src=beep.swf width=0 height=0 loop=false></embed>
</object>
```

Is there something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

changed it to

```
<object type=application/x-shockwave-flash data=beep.swf width=0 height=0>
    <param name=movie value=beep.swf />
    <param name=loop value=false>
</object>
```

and it worked.